# Open UPI link in same window

Tags: javascript, upi

I am trying to integrate UPI in mobile browser. I need to open app tray in browser from where user can select any app and can do the payment.

[image: UPI]

To open App tray, we need to hit a url:

> UPILINK = upi://pay?pa=xyz&pn=pqr&tr=abc&am=1000

I am trying two ways to hit above url:

1. window.open("UPILINK", '_blank');

   This is opening in new window, but pop is blocked warning is shown first.
2. window.location.href = "UPILINK";

   In this approach, user is returned back to previous page.

Do we have any way to open App tray for api hit?

Answer (score 1):

Try define a function

```
redirect() {
    window.location = "upi://pay?pa=xyz&pn=pqr&tr=abc&am=1000";
}
```

And on a button click event bind this function.

It will open up the Apps tray with all the UPI installed in the corresponding mobile.

Comment: hi, how your getting transaction status by using above method ?

Comment: I have a doubt , How do i add a discription in UPI URL ?

Comment: How to get status of payment. Is there a url on the server than can be sent to UPI app to get transaction status?